# "SocialInfoExtractor Operator error in CTS flow" issue coming in SharePoint 2013 Crawl logs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

[image]**"SocialInfoExtractor Operator error in CTS flow" issue coming in Crawl logs**

When i start the full crawl facing above issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by the custom user profile properties within the User Profile Service Application.

Another cause based on my research, it would be the "AccountName" managed property has extra crawled property mappings in it. Check the "AccountName" managed property and see what crawled property mappings are in it. If they have anything other than “People:AccountName”, remove the extra mappings and check if it works.

A thread about SocialInfoExtractor Operator error in CTS flow issue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/72bb0f0f-8193-4e00-9886-51d89b93ee05/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-service-search-crawl-errors?forum=sharepointsearch